Have you seen this logarithmic inequality: $4\log(x)\log(y) \leq \log(xy)^2$
I have stumbled upon this following logarithmic inequality relating the product of two logs. For every $x,y > 0$
$$
4\log(x)\log(y) \leq \log(xy)^2.
$$
Furthermore, it holds as an equality if and only if $x=y$. By standard logarithmic rules this is obviously equivalent to
$$
\log(x)\log(y) \leq \log(\sqrt{xy})^2,
$$
which shows a nice symmetry. My question is if this is a known fact. My intuition would say so, yet I haven't found any source. But I have to admit I also haven't searched for too long or rigorously. The proof is as follows. Consider the polynomial
$$
f = (t-\log(x))(t-\log(y)) = t^2 - (\log(x) + \log(y))t + \log(x)\log(y) \in \mathbb{R}[t],
$$
The zeros of $f$ are given by
$$
\frac{\log(xy)}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{\log(xy)}{2}\right)^2 - \log(x)\log(y)}.
$$
Because the zeros are known to be $\log(x)$ and $\log(y)$, which are real, it follows that
$$
\left(\frac{\log(xy)}{2}\right)^2 - \log(x)\log(y) \geq 0.
$$
Furthermore, there exists exactly one zero of $f$, i.e. $\log(x) = \log(y)$, if and only if the inequality assumes equality.

Does $\log (xy)^2$ mean $\log[(xy)^2]$ or does it mean $(\log(xy))^2$?

This looks like the AM/GM ineq.  $4\log x \log y\le (\log x + \log y)^2$ or $4AB \le (A+B)^2$ or $2\sqrt A \sqrt B \le A+B$ and ... yeah... that is exactly the AM/GM ineq.

... exactly the AM/GM if $A,B$ are non-negative.  But if one of $\log x$ or $\log y$ is negative and the other not we get $4\log x\log y \le 0 \le (\log(xy))^2$.  And if both are negative we $4AB = 4|A||B| \le (A+B)^2 = (|A|+|B|)^2$ or $2\sqrt{|A|}\sqrt{|A|} \le |A| + |B|$ which is exactly the AM/GM.

From the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric means, we know that
$$
\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}2.
$$
Thus we get
$$
\sqrt{\log x\log y}\le\frac{\log x+\log y}2=\frac{\log (xy)}2,
$$
and so
$$
4\log x\log y\le\frac{\log x+\log y}2=\log (xy)^2
$$
(with the proper hypotheses on $x$ and $y$).

A minor problem: $\log x$ and $\log y$ may not be positive and $\sqrt{\log x \log y}$ might not be real. You have to use $4ab\le (a+b)^2 \text{ for all } a,b\in \mathbb R$ instead of $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a+b}2 \text{ for all } a,b>0$ to get the correct proof

and I think there's a typo in your Line 6:)

Minor nitpick.  What of $\log x$ or $\log y$ or both are negative?

@Cyankite a minor problem, but one easily fixed.  If both are negatives it is equivalent to proving for the absolute values of the logs.  If one or the other but not both are negative you have $\log x \log y \le 0 \le [\log xy]^2$.  I would call those minor cases to consider rather then declare this to not be "the correct proof".

@fleablood so I called this a minor problem. I dont think there's any difference in our views

A quicker way :
$\begin{align}4\log(x)\log(y)&\leqslant4\log(x)\log(y)+\big[\log(x)-\log(y)\big]^2=\\[3pt]&=\big[\log(x)+\log(y)\big]^2=\\[3pt]&=\big[\log(xy)\big]^2.\end{align}$

Looks like it's based on the AM-GM inequality. For nonnegative $x$ and $y$,
$$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{x+y}{2}$$
Take $x=\log a$ and $y = \log b$:
$$\sqrt{\log a \log b} \leq \frac{\log a+\log b}{2}$$
$$2\sqrt{\log a \log b} \leq \log ab$$
$$4\log a \log b\leq (\log ab)^2$$

$$
\begin{align}
(\log xy)^2 - 4\log(x)\log(y) &= (\log x + \log y)^2 - 4\log x \log y \\
&= (\log x)^2 + 2 \log x \log y + (\log y) ^2 - 4\log x \log y \\
&= (\log x)^2 - 2 \log x \log y + (\log y) ^2 \\
&= (\log x - \log y)^2\\
\end{align}
$$
So this quantity is always positive, and only zero if $\log x = \log y$.
(This is really just me writing out the proof of the AM-GM inequality, which the other answers went to directly. :-)
